# How do I add WebForms back in ASP.NET 5 RC1?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-core

In AspNet5 rc 1, web application project For loading of html / js pages,

1. by default aspx pages are not supported.

   app.UseStaticFiles()

this allows to browse static html files.  how to add web form, aspx functionality (dnx451, dnxcore50)

2. What are the allowed file extensions / mimetypes in aspnet5 by default. Asking this because, after adding static files functionality, calling that website/test.html page loads fine , but browsing website/test.aspx returns 404 but the pages are available under wwwroot folder inside the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. WebForms are not supported in ASP.NET 5. Thus, serving aspx is not supported.
2. The list of allowed file extensions is here: https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/657a5ab26bea3f0b9293a216f28f7b37e004d707/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs

Comment: thx for quick reply. is it possible to add any aspx middlewares and support webforms? (similar to static file middleware). any easy way to migrate from aspx to new approach, bcoz manually porting all the pages is a lot work

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not aware of any middleware that does that... aspx is more than just serving the content of that file

Comment: ASPX lives on the old pipeline. If they tried to port it over, it wouldn't be WebForms. It would be something else that looked like WebForms but nothing in your old code would work. So why port it? It's not supported. For all intent and purposes... it's dead (for me at least).